# Woocommerce Pop up for categories and remove price from homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Good Morning

i have a woocommerce website, using visual composer i have added featured product and recent product in Homepage, How can we hide Price from featured and recent products?

I tried following code

```
remove_action( woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title','woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10 );
```

This will remove price from Shop, How we can do for visual composer featured products. Any suggestion.

And also is there any plugin in woocommerce, from that we can click a category that will show pop up message once clicked i need to enter that category?

Comment: are you getting any specific `class` or `ID` on `Div` ?

Comment: This is the div "woocommerce columns-4" its for featured and recent products if we used in Visual Composer.

Comment: what is woocommerce version ? `2.1.0` ?

Comment: i think `Visual Composer` is a paid plugin page builder ? is it ?

Comment: yes. it is paid plugin

Comment: you would need to contact plugin developer or you may need to customize the code as per your need. if you customize it do not forget to disabled automatic updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file named `class-custom_shortcodes.php` in your theme folder and Add this code in `functions.php`.

What I have  changed i have added custom class to featured and recent products.

> Class for Featured Product : `custom_featured`
>
> Class for Recent Product : `custom_recent_products`

Use above classes to hide the price on the home page by using function `print_my_inline_style_custom`.

```
function print_my_inline_style_custom() {
   if(is_home()) { 
    echo '<style type="text/css">
            .custom_featured , custom_recent_products {
            display:none;
            }
            </style>';
            }
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'print_my_inline_style_custom' );
```

**class-custom_shortcodes.php**

```
<?php

class WC_Custom_Shortcodes {

    /**
     * Init shortcodes
     */
    public static function init() {


        // Define shortcodes
        $shortcodes = array(
            'product'                    => __CLASS__ . '::product',
            'product_page'               => __CLASS__ . '::product_page',
            'product_category'           => __CLASS__ . '::product_category',
            'product_categories'         => __CLASS__ . '::product_categories',
            'add_to_cart'                => __CLASS__ . '::product_add_to_cart',
            'add_to_cart_url'            => __CLASS__ . '::product_add_to_cart_url',
            'products'                   => __CLASS__ . '::products',
            'recent_products'            => __CLASS__ . '::recent_products',
            'sale_products'              => __CLASS__ . '::sale_products',
            'best_selling_products'      => __CLASS__ . '::best_selling_products',
            'top_rated_products'         => __CLASS__ . '::top_rated_products',
            'featured_products'          => __CLASS__ . '::featured_products',
            'product_attribute'          => __CLASS__ . '::product_attribute',
            'related_products'           => __CLASS__ . '::related_products',
            'shop_messages'              => __CLASS__ . '::shop_messages',
            'woocommerce_order_tracking' => __CLASS__ . '::order_tracking',
            'woocommerce_cart'           => __CLASS__ . '::cart',
            'woocommerce_checkout'       => __CLASS__ . '::checkout',
            'woocommerce_my_account'     => __CLASS__ . '::my_account',
        );

        foreach ( $shortcodes as $shortcode => $function ) {
            add_shortcode( apply_filters( "{$shortcode}_shortcode_tag", $shortcode ), $function );
        }

        // Alias for pre 2.1 compatibility
        add_shortcode( 'woocommerce_messages', __CLASS__ . '::shop_messages' );
    }

    /**
     * Shortcode Wrapper
     *
     * @param mixed $function
     * @param array $atts (default: array())
     * @return string
     */
    public static function shortcode_wrapper(
        $function,
        $atts    = array(),
        $wrapper = array(
            'class'  => 'woocommerce',
            'before' => null,
            'after'  => null
        )
    ) {
        ob_start();

        $before = empty( $wrapper['before'] ) ? '<div class="' . esc_attr( $wrapper['class'] ) . '">' : $wrapper['before'];
        $after  = empty( $wrapper['after'] ) ? '</div>' : $wrapper['after'];

        echo $before;
        call_user_func( $function, $atts );
        echo $after;

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Cart page shortcode.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function cart() {
        if ( ! is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
            return self::shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_Cart', 'output' ) );
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Checkout page shortcode.
     *
     * @param mixed $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function checkout( $atts ) {
        return self::shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_Checkout', 'output' ), $atts );
    }

    /**
     * Order tracking page shortcode.
     *
     * @param mixed $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function order_tracking( $atts ) {
        return self::shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_Order_Tracking', 'output' ), $atts );
    }

    /**
     * Cart shortcode.
     *
     * @param mixed $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function my_account( $atts ) {
        return self::shortcode_wrapper( array( 'WC_Shortcode_My_Account', 'output' ), $atts );
    }

    /**
     * List products in a category shortcode
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product_category( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page' => '12',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'orderby'  => 'title',
            'order'    => 'desc',
            'category' => '',  // Slugs
            'operator' => 'IN' // Possible values are 'IN', 'NOT IN', 'AND'.
        ), $atts );

        if ( ! $atts['category'] ) {
            return '';
        }

        // Default ordering args
        $ordering_args = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args( $atts['orderby'], $atts['order'] );
        $meta_query    = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'orderby'               => $ordering_args['orderby'],
            'order'                 => $ordering_args['order'],
            'posts_per_page'        => $atts['per_page'],
            'meta_query'            => $meta_query,
            'tax_query'             => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy'      => 'product_cat',
                    'terms'         => array_map( 'sanitize_title', explode( ',', $atts['category'] ) ),
                    'field'         => 'slug',
                    'operator'      => $atts['operator']
                )
            )
        );

        if ( isset( $ordering_args['meta_key'] ) ) {
            $args['meta_key'] = $ordering_args['meta_key'];
        }

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_before_product_cat_loop' ); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_shortcode_after_product_cat_loop' ); ?>

        <?php endif;

        woocommerce_reset_loop();
        wp_reset_postdata();

        $return = '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';

        // Remove ordering query arguments
        WC()->query->remove_ordering_args();

        return $return;
    }


    /**
     * List all (or limited) product categories
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product_categories( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'number'     => null,
            'orderby'    => 'name',
            'order'      => 'ASC',
            'columns'    => '4',
            'hide_empty' => 1,
            'parent'     => '',
            'ids'        => ''
        ), $atts );

        if ( isset( $atts['ids'] ) ) {
            $ids = explode( ',', $atts['ids'] );
            $ids = array_map( 'trim', $ids );
        } else {
            $ids = array();
        }

        $hide_empty = ( $atts['hide_empty'] == true || $atts['hide_empty'] == 1 ) ? 1 : 0;

        // get terms and workaround WP bug with parents/pad counts
        $args = array(
            'orderby'    => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'      => $atts['order'],
            'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
            'include'    => $ids,
            'pad_counts' => true,
            'child_of'   => $atts['parent']
        );

        $product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );

        if ( '' !== $atts['parent'] ) {
            $product_categories = wp_list_filter( $product_categories, array( 'parent' => $atts['parent'] ) );
        }

        if ( $hide_empty ) {
            foreach ( $product_categories as $key => $category ) {
                if ( $category->count == 0 ) {
                    unset( $product_categories[ $key ] );
                }
            }
        }

        if ( $atts['number'] ) {
            $product_categories = array_slice( $product_categories, 0, $atts['number'] );
        }

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        ob_start();

        // Reset loop/columns globals when starting a new loop
        $woocommerce_loop['loop'] = $woocommerce_loop['column'] = '';

        if ( $product_categories ) {

            woocommerce_product_loop_start();

            foreach ( $product_categories as $category ) {

                wc_get_template( 'content-product_cat.php', array(
                    'category' => $category
                ) );

            }

            woocommerce_product_loop_end();

        }

        woocommerce_reset_loop();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Recent Products shortcode
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function recent_products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page'  => '12',
            'columns'   => '4',
            'orderby'   => 'date',
            'order'     => 'desc'
        ), $atts );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'             => 'product',
            'post_status'           => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
            'posts_per_page'        => $atts['per_page'],
            'orderby'               => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'                 => $atts['order'],
            'meta_query'            => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce custom_recent_products columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }


    /**
     * List multiple products shortcode
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'columns' => '4',
            'orderby' => 'title',
            'order'   => 'asc',
            'ids'     => '',
            'skus'    => ''
        ), $atts );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'               => $atts['order'],
            'posts_per_page'      => -1,
            'meta_query'          => $meta_query
        );

        if ( ! empty( $atts['skus'] ) ) {
            $skus = explode( ',', $atts['skus'] );
            $skus = array_map( 'trim', $skus );
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'       => '_sku',
                'value'     => $skus,
                'compare'   => 'IN'
            );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $atts['ids'] ) ) {
            $ids = explode( ',', $atts['ids'] );
            $ids = array_map( 'trim', $ids );
            $args['post__in'] = $ids;
        }

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }


    /**
     * Display a single product
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product( $atts ) {
        if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'no_found_rows'  => 1,
            'post_status'    => 'publish',
            'meta_query'     => $meta_query
        );

        if ( isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'       => '_sku',
                'value'     => $atts['sku'],
                'compare'   => '='
            );
        }

        if ( isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            $args['p'] = $atts['id'];
        }

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        $css_class = 'woocommerce';

        if ( isset( $atts['class'] ) ) {

            $css_class .= ' ' . $atts['class'];
        }

        return '<div class="' . esc_attr( $css_class ) . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Display a single product price + cart button
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product_add_to_cart( $atts ) {
        global $wpdb, $post;

        if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'id'         => '',
            'class'      => '',
            'quantity'   => '1',
            'sku'        => '',
            'style'      => 'border:4px solid #ccc; padding: 12px;',
            'show_price' => 'true'
        ), $atts );

        if ( ! empty( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            $product_data = get_post( $atts['id'] );
        } elseif ( ! empty( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
            $product_id   = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $atts['sku'] );
            $product_data = get_post( $product_id );
        } else {
            return '';
        }

        $product = wc_setup_product_data( $product_data );

        if ( ! $product ) {
            return '';
        }

        ob_start();
        ?>
        <p class="product woocommerce add_to_cart_inline <?php echo $atts['class']; ?>" style="<?php echo $atts['style']; ?>">

            <?php if ( 'true' == $atts['show_price'] ) : ?>
                <?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( array( 'quantity' => $atts['quantity'] ) ); ?>

        </p><?php

        // Restore Product global in case this is shown inside a product post
        wc_setup_product_data( $post );

        return ob_get_clean();
    }

    /**
     * Get the add to cart URL for a product
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product_add_to_cart_url( $atts ) {
        global $wpdb;

        if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        if ( isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            $product_data = get_post( $atts['id'] );
        } elseif ( isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
            $product_id   = wc_get_product_id_by_sku( $atts['sku'] );
            $product_data = get_post( $product_id );
        } else {
            return '';
        }

        if ( 'product' !== $product_data->post_type ) {
            return '';
        }

        $_product = wc_get_product( $product_data );

        return esc_url( $_product->add_to_cart_url() );
    }

    /**
     * List all products on sale
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function sale_products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page' => '12',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'orderby'  => 'title',
            'order'    => 'asc'
        ), $atts );

        // Get products on sale
        $product_ids_on_sale = wc_get_product_ids_on_sale();

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'    => $atts['per_page'],
            'orderby'           => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'             => $atts['order'],
            'no_found_rows'     => 1,
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'post_type'         => 'product',
            'meta_query'        => $meta_query,
            'post__in'          => array_merge( array( 0 ), $product_ids_on_sale )
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * List best selling products on sale
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function best_selling_products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page' => '12',
            'columns'  => '4'
        ), $atts );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
            'meta_key'            => 'total_sales',
            'orderby'             => 'meta_value_num',
            'meta_query'          => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * List top rated products on sale
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function top_rated_products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page' => '12',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'orderby'  => 'title',
            'order'    => 'asc'
        ), $atts );

        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'               => $atts['order'],
            'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
            'meta_query'          => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        add_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( __CLASS__, 'order_by_rating_post_clauses' ) );

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', array( __CLASS__, 'order_by_rating_post_clauses' ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * Output featured products
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function featured_products( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page' => '12',
            'columns'  => '4',
            'orderby'  => 'date',
            'order'    => 'desc'
        ), $atts );

        $meta_query   = WC()->query->get_meta_query();
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'key'   => '_featured',
            'value' => 'yes'
        );

        $args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
            'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'               => $atts['order'],
            'meta_query'          => $meta_query
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce custom_featured columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }


    /**
     * Show a single product page
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product_page( $atts ) {
        if ( empty( $atts ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        if ( ! isset( $atts['id'] ) && ! isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
            return '';
        }

        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'      => 1,
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'no_found_rows'       => 1
        );

        if ( isset( $atts['sku'] ) ) {
            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => '_sku',
                'value'   => $atts['sku'],
                'compare' => '='
            );
        }

        if ( isset( $atts['id'] ) ) {
            $args['p'] = $atts['id'];
        }

        $single_product = new WP_Query( $args );

        ob_start();

        while ( $single_product->have_posts() ) : $single_product->the_post(); wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-single-product' ); ?>

            <div class="single-product">

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' ); ?>

            </div>

        <?php endwhile; // end of the loop.

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }


    /**
     * Show messages
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public static function shop_messages() {
        ob_start();

        wc_print_notices();

        return '<div class="woocommerce">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * woocommerce_order_by_rating_post_clauses function.
     *
     * @param array $args
     * @return array
     */
    public static function order_by_rating_post_clauses( $args ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $args['where'] .= " AND $wpdb->commentmeta.meta_key = 'rating' ";

        $args['join'] .= "
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->comments ON($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->comments.comment_post_ID)
            LEFT JOIN $wpdb->commentmeta ON($wpdb->comments.comment_ID = $wpdb->commentmeta.comment_id)
        ";

        $args['orderby'] = "$wpdb->commentmeta.meta_value DESC";

        $args['groupby'] = "$wpdb->posts.ID";

        return $args;
    }


    /**
     * List products with an attribute shortcode
     * Example [product_attribute attribute='color' filter='black']
     *
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function product_attribute( $atts ) {
        global $woocommerce_loop;

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'per_page'  => '12',
            'columns'   => '4',
            'orderby'   => 'title',
            'order'     => 'asc',
            'attribute' => '',
            'filter'    => ''
        ), $atts );

        $attribute  = strstr( $atts['attribute'], 'pa_' ) ? sanitize_title( $atts['attribute'] ) : 'pa_' . sanitize_title( $atts['attribute'] );
        $meta_query = WC()->query->get_meta_query();

        $args = array(
            'post_type'           => 'product',
            'post_status'         => 'publish',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'posts_per_page'      => $atts['per_page'],
            'orderby'             => $atts['orderby'],
            'order'               => $atts['order'],
            'meta_query'          => $meta_query,
            'tax_query'           => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => $attribute,
                    'terms'    => array_map( 'sanitize_title', explode( ',', $atts['filter'] ) ),
                    'field'    => 'slug'
                )
            )
        );

        ob_start();

        $products = new WP_Query( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', $args, $atts ) );

        $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $atts['columns'];

        if ( $products->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

                <?php while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post(); ?>

                    <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php endif;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        return '<div class="woocommerce columns-' . $atts['columns'] . '">' . ob_get_clean() . '</div>';
    }

    /**
     * @param array $atts
     * @return string
     */
    public static function related_products( $atts ) {

        $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'posts_per_page' => '2',
            'columns'        => '2',
            'orderby'        => 'rand',
            'per_page'       => ''
        ), $atts );

        if ( ! empty( $atts['per_page'] ) ) {
            _deprecated_argument( __CLASS__ . '->' . __FUNCTION__, '2.1', __( 'Use $args["posts_per_page"] instead. Deprecated argument will be removed in WC 2.2.', 'woocommerce' ) );
            $atts['posts_per_page'] = $atts['per_page'];
            unset( $atts['per_page'] );
        }

        ob_start();

        woocommerce_related_products( $atts );

        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}
```

It will remove default Woocommerce shortcodes class action
And add our action.

load our custom shortcodes class which is copy of origional file [class-wc-shortcodes.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-shortcodes.php).

```
include_once('class-custom_shortcodes.php');

add_action( 'init', 'use_custom_wc_shortcodes' );
function use_custom_wc_shortcodes()
{
    remove_action('init', array('WC_Shortcodes', 'init'));
}
// hook in ours
add_action('init', array('WC_Custom_Shortcodes', 'init'));
```

Comment: Perfect Noman for 1st question, any plugin for second question?